# Delete div via jquery by clicking on input in it

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with deleting div via jquery by clicking on input in it.

My code:

```
<div id="comment"></div>
<div id="comment"></div>
<div id="comment"></div>
<div id="comment"> // one of these div

    <img src="some picture"></img>
    <div></div> //some divs
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <input id="submit-comment-delete" type="submit" value=""></input>

</div>
```

After click on input I need to hide the main div `comment`.

My jquery code:

```
$("#submit-comment-delete").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: some,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                if (data == "success") {
                        //hide div `comment`
                } else {
                    alert(data + " error");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You can only have ONE div with id comment, you need to change those for classes.

Comment: your random edit might be confusion for us. please consider first then only ask what problem you have.

Comment: C-link Sorry I didnt have much time... next question will be better

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple divs with id comment. Change them to use a class and use .closest() to find that div.

```
<div class="comment"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#submit-comment").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: some,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data == "success") {
                    $(this).closest('.comment').remove();
            } else {
                alert(data + " error");
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

Using your code - but at the moment I do not see why you have an ajax call in the first place? Or have you just omitted the data?

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly thanks man I will learn more about closest.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, jQuery based solution :

```
$('#submit-comment-delete').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit-comment-delete").click(function()
{
$("#comment").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()`

```
$('#submit-comment-delete').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WjHv7/)

Answer (score 0):

Use closest() function to select the closer `#comment` div hide() function to hide or remove() function to remove:

```
$("#submit-comment-delete").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: some,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                if (data == "success") {
                        //hide div `comment`
                 $(this).closest('.comment').hide(); //used class selector instead
                } else {
                    alert(data + " error");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

---

End note: Use class instead of id for same attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jquery [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) here:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="comment1">
    <img src="some picture"></img>
    <div></div> //some divs
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <input id="submit-comment-delete1" type="submit" value="Click here"></input>
</div>

<div id="comment2">
    <img src="some picture"></img>
    <div>//some divs</div> 
    <div>//some divs</div>
    <div>//some divs</div>
    <input id="submit-comment-delete2" type="submit" value="Click here"></input>    
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){    
    $('input').click(function (){
    $(this).parent().hide();// If you only want to hide  
     //$(this).parent().remove(); // If you want to remove  
    });
});
```

[Try in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gCs8K/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('#submit-comment-delete').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WjHv7/2/)**